# Unable to make text bold in SVG

Tags: html, css, angular, svg

I have something like this:

```css
.speed-description {
  font-size: calculate-rem(9px);
}
```

```html
<svg #speedAnimation class="{{ speedAnimationClass }}" viewBox="-10 50 140 80" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
  <path class="loader" d="m 0 120 a 1 1 0 0 1 120 0" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="11" />
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="60" y="110" font-weight="900" ></text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="60" y="120" font-weight="bold" class="speed-description">
    {{ speedDescription }}
  </text>
</svg>
```

Whatever I try I cannot make the 2 texts in bold.
What am I doing wrong?

Currently it's something like this

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post and the snippet to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Well that's my whole code and the css and also the output...

Comment: This works as designed at least in Chrome/Win. If this isn't working for you - you probably have CSS elsewhere that is over-riding these font-weights.

Comment: It works for me. But just in case: in SVG you can add a `stroke` to the text. This will make the text look like bold. You can use a `stroke-width` to set it as bold as you need. Also you can use [<feMorphology>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feMorphology)

Comment: @enxaneta Most likely there's some imported css that's messing up my font-weight, but your stroke/stroke-width worked so you could make it as an answer for me to approve it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've commented:  in SVG you can add a stroke to the text. This will make the text look like bold. You can use a stroke-width to set it as bold as you need.

```css
text{stroke:black; stroke-width:.5}
```

```html
<svg #speedAnimation class="speedAnimationClass" viewBox="-10 50 140 80" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="60" y="100" >some text</text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="60" y="120" class="speed-description">speed Description</text>
</svg>
```

Alternatively you can use `<feMorphology>` for this. In this case you will need to play with the value of the radius attribute of the `<feMorphology>`

```html
 <svg #speedAnimation class="speedAnimationClass" viewBox="-10 50 140 80" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
  <filter id="dilate">
    <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius=".5"/>
  </filter>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="60" y="100" filter="url(#dilate)" >some text</text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="60" y="120" class="speed-description" filter="url(#dilate)">speed Description</text>
</svg>
```